# mongodb Cannot apply $pull/$pullAll modifier to non-array, How to remove array element

Tags: mongodb

i met a problem about mongodb.

```
db.tt.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("513c971be4b1f9d71bc8c769"), 
  "name" : "a", 
  "comments" : [ { "name" : "2" }, { "name" : "3" } ] 
}
```

above is a test document.

i want to pull comments.name = 2

i do

```
db.tt.update({'comments.name':'2'},{'$pull':{'comments.$.name':'2'}});
```

but the console print these message:

Cannot apply $pull/$pullAll modifier to non-array

my mongodb version is 2.0.6

who can help me? Thank you very much

Comment: I think the `$` symbol in your query is not needed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `$pull` syntax is off, it should be:

```
db.tt.update({'comments.name': '2'}, {$pull: {comments: {name: '2'}}})
```

Comment: db.col.find() {
    "_id" : ObjectId("d53d7810352eaec7c154b711"),
    "name" : "Amount",
    "type" : "text",   
    "message" : {
        "test value" : 1,
        "test value1" : 6
    }
}                                                                                                                    db.col.update({"_id":ObjectId("d53d7810352eaec7c154b711")},{$pull :{"message": {"test value" : 1}}});                                                                                                                           i tried this it is not working for me

Comment: @RaviKumar Please post that as a new question if you're still having trouble.

Comment: With what this "{$pull: {comments: {name: '2'}}}" can be replaced,to make it accept string as question poster was trying.