# How to remove a particular element from a nested array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

My Document structure is

```
"MainAccounts" : [ 
    {
        "orgs" : "5808ba773fe315441b9e0a9e",
        "_id" : ObjectId("5808bc0c3fe315441b9e0b1a"),
        "accounts" : [ 
            "5808baf33fe315441b9e0aa7", 
            "5808baf33fe315441b9e0aa8", 
            "5808baf33fe315441b9e0aa9", 
            "5808baf33fe315441b9e0aa1"
        ]
    },
     {
        "orgs" : "5808ba773fe315441b9e0a9f",
        "_id" : ObjectId("5808bc0c3fe315441b9e0b1b"),
        "accounts" : [ 
            "5808baf33f35425852s255s7", 
            "5808baf3sd23s2d3d4w5s2s8", 
            "5808baf33sd211ds2d2sdsa9", 
            "5808baf33dssd2d21b9e0aa1"
        ]
    }
],
```

I want to pull out a particular account say "5808baf33fe315441b9e0aa8" from this, i wrote the query like this.

```
{ $pull: { "MainAccounts.$.accounts": "5808baf33fe315441b9e0aa8"} }
```

It gives only error as "The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: MainAccounts.$.accounts"

```
 { $pull: { "MainAccounts.0.accounts": "5808baf33fe315441b9e0aa8" } }
```

If i give like this it will remove that value only which gives the expected output.

i need output as

```
 "MainAccounts" : [ 
    {
        "orgs" : "5808ba773fe315441b9e0a9e",
        "_id" : ObjectId("5808bc0c3fe315441b9e0b1a"),
        "accounts" : [ 
            "5808baf33fe315441b9e0aa7",                 
            "5808baf33fe315441b9e0aa9", 
            "5808baf33fe315441b9e0aa1"
        ]
    },
     {
        "orgs" : "5808ba773fe315441b9e0a9f",
        "_id" : ObjectId("5808bc0c3fe315441b9e0b1b"),
        "accounts" : [ 
            "5808baf33f35425852s255s7", 
            "5808baf3sd23s2d3d4w5s2s8", 
            "5808baf33sd211ds2d2sdsa9", 
            "5808baf33dssd2d21b9e0aa1"
        ]
    }
],
```

here i am not able to delete value from second array i need to give

```
 { $pull: { "MainAccounts.1.accounts": "5808baf33fe315441b9e0aa8" } }
```

But i need to loop through, any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is `someId`? The positional `$` operator usage is correct, but the requirement for that to work is actually matching the element in the "query" part, which is what should be in `someId`. What is `MainAccounts`? is that actually part of the collection or part of your document? If part of the document, then we have other problems here.

Comment: try this one : collection.update(someId, { $pull: { "MainAccounts.accounts": req.params.accountId } })

Comment: @Neil Lunn Please leave all the things "someId". kindly consider my $pull -query.  how can i pull out a particular element from that nested array-               { $pull : {"MainAccounts.$.accounts" : "5808baf33fe315441b9e0aa8" } }

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228210/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-doubly-nested-array-in-a-mongodb-document

Answer (score 1):

You will get an error:
"Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value"

This should be :

```
db.collection.update({'MainAccounts.accounts': '5808baf33fe315441b9e0aa8'}, {$pull: {MainAccounts:{ accounts: '5808baf33fe315441b9e0aa8'}}})
```

Here is a reference to this:

[mongodb Cannot apply $pull/$pullAll modifier to non-array, How to remove array element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323422/mongodb-cannot-apply-pull-pullall-modifier-to-non-array-how-to-remove-array-e)

Comment: The above command will remove the whole nested json(orgs, _id, accounts) not just 5808baf33fe315441b9e0aa8

Answer (score -1):

db.collection.update({someId,{$pull : {"MainAccounts":{"accounts":"5808baf33fe315441b9e0aa8"}}}})

someId could be your _id. 
Remember if you have to access the document inside the array you cant access it without . operator only.You have to use the index with it.The other way mongodb can access it is by the use of braces.

Comment: Hi This one also removes all the accounts array elements instead of only 5808baf33fe315441b9e0aa8.

Answer (score -1):

This will do what you want:

`db.collection.update({'MainAccounts.accounts': '5808baf33fe315441b9e0aa8'}, {$pull: {'MainAccounts.$.accounts': '5808baf33fe315441b9e0aa8'}})`

Comment: This also does the same, account array consisting of `5808baf33fe315441b9e0aa8` is getting removed

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. You wrote that removing that value only gives the expected output and the above code will do that.

Comment: Hi andrew, this code gives `"MainAccounts" : [ 
    {
        "orgs" : "5808ba773fe315441b9e0a9e",
        "_id" : ObjectId("5808bc0c3fe315441b9e0b1a"),
        "accounts" : [  ]
    },`  but what i need is to remove only that particular value `"MainAccounts" : [ 
    {
        "orgs" : "5808ba773fe315441b9e0a9e",
        "_id" : ObjectId("5808bc0c3fe315441b9e0b1a"),
        "accounts" : [ 
            "5808baf33fe315441b9e0aa7",           
            "5808baf33fe315441b9e0aa9", 
            "5808baf33fe315441b9e0aa1"
        ]
    },}` , this is what i need

Comment: See my answer. I got a "Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value" when doing this one.